# How to mock initialized objects declared outside the method which is to be tested

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have below class.. Need to set mock values for "EmployeeInterfaceFactory.getAddressImpl()".. Tried using PowerMock, but as the declaration is outside the method, Mocked object is not getting reflected and NullPointerException is coming.. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

```
public Address address(){

private EmpAddress empAddress = EmployeeInterfaceFactory.getAddressImpl();

public String getDetails(){

String details = empAddress.getEmpDetails();
return details;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code from`EmployeeInterfaceFactory.getAddressImpl()` ?

Comment: "EmployeeInterfaceFactory" is in different package and don't have control over it...

Comment: You don't have the code for it? Can you atleast share the decompiled code for it?

Comment: "EmployeeInterfaceFactory" is added as dependency (pom) to my module.. That's why can't share.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks a little bit incorrect. I assume following code:

```java
public Address{
  private EmpAddress empAddress = EmployeeInterfaceFactory.getAddressImpl();

  public String getDetails(){
    String details = empAddress.getEmpDetails();
    return details;
  }
}
```

Then you could just inject the `EmployeeInterfaceFactory` in a constructor:

```java
public Address{
  private EmpAddress empAddress;

  public Address(EmployeeInterfaceFactory employeeFactory){
    empAddress = employeeFactory.getAddressImpl();
  }

  public String getDetails(){
    String details = empAddress.getEmpDetails();
    return details;
  }
}
```

This way you can use normal mockito functions to mock objects.

```java
EmployeeInterfaceFactory  employeeFactory = mock(EmployeeInterfaceFactory.class);
AddressImpl employeeAddress = new AddressImpl();
//set details on employeeAddress
when(employeeFactory.getAddressImpl()).thenReturn(employeeAddress);
```

So in general this is pushing up a dependecy to the caller (see refactoring methods for more information).